# Post Thumbnails on Sidebar Widgets

Tags: widgets, post-thumbnails, sidebar

How do I get my post thumbnails to show up on the recent post widget or a commenter's avatar to show up on the recent comments widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ability in the default widget, you will need to use third-party plugins to acheive your goal.

Here are some that I have found.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yd-recent-posts-widget/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-recent-comments/